# MonoMac / Xamarin.Mac: EntryPointNotFoundException for AudioSession.Initialize()

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin, monomac

I'm very new to C#, MonoMac and Xamarin and am trying to play some generated audio with C# and Xamarin.Mac using [this awesome example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11812441/1240061).

Unforunately the first line:

```
AudioSession.Initialize();
```

throws an **EntryPointNotFoundException**.

I've stumbled upon [this forum post](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-osx/2013-January/005173.html) where someone is having a similar problem and suggests that it has to do with an incorrect binding.

Can I actually get this to work? If not, what can I use instead?

Thank you so much for your help.

## My System

> Xamarin.Mac: 1.2.43
>
> Xamarin.Studio Version 4.0.3 (build 13)
>
> Mono 2.10.12 (mono-2-10/c9b270d)
>
> GTK 2.24.16
>
> GTK# (2.12.0.0)
>
> Package version: 210120000

## Stack Trace

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: AudioSessionInitialize
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.AudioSessionInitialize (intptr,intptr,MonoMac.AudioToolbox.AudioSession/InterruptionListener,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0007b>
  at MonoMac.AudioToolbox.AudioSession.Initialize (MonoMac.CoreFoundation.CFRunLoop,string) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/xamcore-lion-bs1/0c83ca0e/source/xamcore/maccore/src/AudioToolbox/AudioSession.cs:225
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that AudioSession is not used on OS X.

The sample code you are working from is likely for iOS.

If you check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) for AudioSession, you will see:

```
These functions apply only to iOS. They do not apply to Mac OS X.
```

Additionally, see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932954/port-ios-app-to-mac-os-xaudio-capture-and-playback). AudioSession is simply not available, which is why you get EntryPointNotFoundException when trying to call it...